# How to fix infinite loop within assembly language code:

Tags: assembly, pep8-assembly

So I am running and creating this program for homework where I input a couple of chars where I then compare it to 7 and keep count of how many 7s have been input until the # sign ends the program. For some reason, I somehow get stuck in this infinite loop. I feel like my logic is okay, but I simply do not understand what is causing it to be stuck in an infinite loop.

```
 main:    LDX 0, i            ;load 0 to acc
          STX charCoun, d     ;store 0 to charcount
 while:   CHARI charIn, d     ;get char input
          LDA charIn, d       ;load input to acc
          CPA 35, i           ;compare to char #
          BREQ endWhile       ;if it equals to # branch to end while
          CPA 55, i           ;compare to char 7
          BREQ count7         ;branch to count 7 if equal to char 7
          BR while            ;otherwise loop
```

Comment: It's not branching correctly to other branches within the while branch.

Comment: What assembly is this? PEP8?

Comment: Yes it's PEP8. I just realized my mistake in not loading charIn as a byte into the accumulator.

Comment: So basically I'msuppose to have 
     LDBYTE charIn, d